# Remove a field from YAML OpenAPI specification

Tags: yaml, openapi

I need to remove the `tags` field from each of the methods in my OpenAPI spec.
The spec must be in YAML format, as converting to JSON causes issues later on when publishing.

I couldn't find a ready tool for that, and my programming skills are insufficient. I tried Python with ruamel.yaml, but could not achieve anything.

I'm open to any suggestions how to approach this - a repo with a ready tool somewhere, a hint on what to try in Python... I'm out of my own ideas.

Maybe a regex that catches all cases all instances of `tags` so I can do a search and replace with Python, replacing them with nothing? Empty lines don't seem to break the publishing engine.

Here's a sample YAML piece (I know this is not a proper spec, just want to show where in the YAML `tags` sits)

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: ""
  description: ""
paths:
  /endpoint
    get:
      tags:
        - 
          tag1
        - 
          tag3
    #rest of GET definition
    post:
      tags:
        - tag2
  /anotherEndpoint
    post:
      tags:
        - tag1
```

I need to get rid of all `tags` arrays entirely (not just make them empty)

Comment: That is not valid YAML, isn't there a value indicator (`:`) after `/endpoint` and `/anotherEndpoint` in your real file?

Comment: @Anthon No, that's a mistake on my side, I typed this by hand to illustrate the layout and forgot about the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you couldn't achieve anything with Python + ruamel.yaml. Assuing your spec
is in a file `input.yaml`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('input.yaml')
out_file = Path('output.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(in_file)

# if you only have the three instances of 'tags', you can hard-code them:
# del data['paths']['/endpoint']['get']['tags']
# del data['paths']['/endpoint']['post']['tags']
# del data['paths']['/anotherEndpoint']['post']['tags']

# generic recursive removal of any key names 'tags' in the datastructure:
def rm_tags(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if 'tags' in d:
            del d['tags']
        for k in d:
            rm_tags(d[k])
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            rm_tags(item)

rm_tags(data)

yaml.dump(data, out_file)
```

which gives as `output.yaml`:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
    title: ""
    description: ""
paths:
    /endpoint:
        get: {}
        post: {}
    /anotherEndpoint:
        post: {}
```

You can write back `data` to `input.yaml` if you need that.

Please note that normally the comment `#rest of GET definition` would be preserved, but
not now as it is associated during loading with the key before it and  that key gets deleted.

Comment: I just don't have enough expertise with Python to figure stuff by myself.
Thanks a lot for the help, I'll try your code first thing in the morning when I'm back at work on Monday!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, my final method only checks for instances of dict, and stops the recursion inside each dict after the third run - in order to leave `tags` in request body and response body definitions.

Comment: Your answer worked, I just added a counter that stops the recursion before it goes deeper than I wanted :)